# How to check when a form was rendered in Laravel

Tags: forms, laravel-5, laravelcollective

Upon a form a submission, I wish to determine the time that a Laravel form (built using the Laravel Collective HTML package) was rendered to the user.

I need to check this date upon submission for a variety of reasons.

I have a large existing project and am considering the best way to get this date. I was reading the CSRF middleware (since this token is already included in all forms) to see if it can be extracted from that, perhaps in another middleware adding something like *form_generated_date* to the request.

It looks like a bit of a stretch, if possible at all. So now I am looking at adding a custom field to every form.

I would like this to be included in all forms, just as the `Form::open()` method will add the CSRF token. I found information on adding my own macros, but not about extending this method.

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the date from a CSRF token? Or how (or where the documentation is) to extend the `Form::open()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `Form::open()` method looks to be in the `FormBuilder.php` file (https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/2f6dc39ab3655724a615fe8a652d8b7f04fc9ac6/src/FormBuilder.php).

This file can be found in  `/vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/FormBuilder.php`

You should be able to add a new hidden form field to the open method, bearing in mind that this will be overwritten in any updates.  Not really recommended, but will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, but editing a vendor package isn't for me :) I was considering extending the FormBuilder into a CustomFormBuilder to override the method. But was hoping there was a method deliberately exposed by the form builder for this purpose, like with Macros. I'll need to make sure dependencies are resolved correctly to my new CustomFormBuilder class in all parts of the application though. I'll post some code back here when I get to it

Comment: I agree :)  As there does not appear to be a way of grabbing the date/time from the token generation, I think making sure a hidden field is added each time you open a form is the way to go.  Just ensure you have specific tests for it.